# Update Component by reactivity way

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below demo has two `Row` components, one of them is dependent on `styles['a']`, another one is dependent on `styles['b']`.

But if update `styles['a']` in place, it will not trigger `re-render`(same object reference)

if update `styles['a']` with new object, it will trigger `re-render` for both `<Row type={'a'}/>` and `<Row type={'b'}/>`.

Is there any way we can implement updating the components based on the dependency? For example, when `styles['a']` is updated, then `<Row type={'a'}/>` will be re-rendered, but `<Row type={'b'}/>` **will not**.

**PS:** I want to transplant one chart library from Vue to React, the chart may have thousands of components are dependent on the `props.options/styles` of the root component. So I don't want to re-render whole chart even if only one property of `options/styles` is changed.

```js
const RootContext = React.createContext("RootOptions")
function Chart({options}) {
  const [styles, setStyles] = React.useState({'a':'a', 'b':'b'})
  const [innerOptions, setOptions] = React.useState({})
  const value = React.useMemo(() => ({options: innerOptions, styles: styles}), [styles, innerOptions])
  return (
    <RootContext.Provider value={value}>
      <Row type={'a'} items={[]}></Row>
      <Row type={'b'} items={[]}></Row>
      <input value={styles['a']} onChange={(e) => {
        setStyles(Object.assign({}, styles, {'a': e.target.value}) // will trigger updateComponent for both Row-'a' and Row-'b'
        // setStyles(Object.assign(styles, {'a': e.target.value}) will not trigger updateComponent
      )}} />
    </RootContext.Provider>
  )
}

function Row(props) {
  const {options, styles} = React.useContext(RootContext)
  console.log('Row rendered ', props.type)
  const value = React.useMemo(() => styles[props.type] + '...', [props.type, styles[props.type]])

  return (
    <div>
      <pre>{props.type}: {value} -> <Cell num={props.type}/></pre>
    </div>
  )
}

function Cell({num}) {
  console.log('Cell rendered', num)
  return <span>{num}</span>
}

ReactDOM.render(<Chart options={{}} />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Below is one similar demo for Vue, you will see only the component=`<test1 :a="test.a">` will be updated when `test.a` is changed.

```js
Vue.component('test1',{
    render (h) {
      return h('p', `test1: ${this.a}`)
    },
    props: ['a'],
    updated: function () {
      console.log('updated sidebar ' + this.a)
    },
    mounted:function () {
      console.log('mounted sidebar ' + this.a)
    }
})

Vue.component('test2',{
    render (h) {
      return h('p', `test2: ${this.b}`)
    },
    props: ['b'],
    updated: function () {
      console.log('updated tool ' + this.b)
    },
    mounted:function () {
      console.log('mounted tool ' + this.b)
    }
})

new Vue ({
  el:'#app',
  data () {
    return {
      test: {'a': 1, 'b': 2222}
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <test1 :a="test.a"></test1>
    <test1 :a="test.b"></test1>
    <test2 :b="test.b"></test2>
    <input v-model="test.a">
</div>
```

Comment: You can convert Row to a class and use `shouldComponentUpdate` lifecycle method in `Row`. Just compare new prop with the state, if both are same, then return false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rows are updating because of the context is being updated as you type. Look at the `style` value.

```
const [styles, setStyles] = React.useState({'a':'a', 'b':'b'})
const [innerOptions, setOptions] = React.useState({})
const value = React.useMemo(() => ({options: innerOptions, styles: styles}), [styles, innerOptions]);
```

Also the `item={[]}` prop  on each row should be static(outside the component) or in state/memo/ref as this will also cause a rendering. Im assuming this is here for simplicity.

A simple solution would be just to not use a global/root context(thats not stable) and to use memo/selectors or even something like [reslect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) to create stable state slices for each `type` then using [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) to skip rendering when props are equal. The obvious downside is that you will need to prop drill those values down and that can get annoying. And probably why you decided to go with context in the first place. Here is an untested example using a memoed selector.

```
const Row = react.memo((props) => ...); // your row component now wrapped with memo.

// im injecting styles, options, ect so that you dont have to keep this code in
// the component because it makes the component code more focused.
// You could move this into a new file, put it directly inside your component, ect. 
const selectRowType = (type, styles, options) => {
  const style = styles[type];

  return useMemo(() => {
    return { options, style };
  }, [style, options]);
};

<Row type={selectRowType('a', styles, innerOptions) items={...} />
<Row type={selectRowType('b', styles, innerOptions) items={...} />
```

A compromise could be to use a `RowContext` inside each row that way the cells and other row children can use context values derived by the `type` and would be stable unless the observed `type` changes in the parent. You would still need to preselect the values for each row type, but would avoid the prop drilling pain inside the `<Row />` boundary.

```
const DEFAULT_ROW_CONTEXT_VALUE = {};
const RowContext = createContext(DEFAULT_ROW_CONTEXT_VALUE );

// create a stable row context value.
// We can further enrich the context with row specific data here.
const selectRowContextValue = (props) => {
  const { type, items } = props;

  return useMemo(() => {
    return { type, items }; 
  }, [type, items]); 
}; 

const Row = React.memo((props) => {
  return (
    <RowContext.Provider value={selectRowContextValue(props)}>
      {...}
    </RowContext.Provider>
  );  
});

<Row type={selectRowType('a', styles, innerOptions) items={...} />
<Row type={selectRowType('b', styles, innerOptions) items={...} />
```

If you have only `<Cell />` children and they arn't deep, then there really isn't a reason to use `RowContext` on every `<Row />`. It's up to you.

Comment: In that Vue chart library, the component tree is very deep and almost all non-root components will need to access `props.options` and `props.styles`, that is why I want to find one solution similar with Vue reactivity (actually it uses `provide/inject`). but anyway, thanks for the answer, probably i have to choose drill props value down to the all leaf components.